# Javascript contact form with contact.php file not found or internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, contacts

I have a contact form on my test website, but when I send the message its providing me the following error

> mail/contact_me.php 404 (Not Found)

But the file is on the server. I'm using Wordpress on the website. I tried to add different things but it still not working. How can I fix this? Check the code below

I tried just to put the `contactform.js` on my index file and change the link with template url but its still not working :(

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Thank you! We'll be in touch very soon. If you'd like to make a reservation in the meantime, please find us on Expedia. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>So sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please call us while we resolve this issue. ");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name          = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message       = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to            = 'test@YOURDOMAIN.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body    = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n" . "Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers       = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
return true;
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no need to add `method` and `action` in your html `form`?

Comment: @ColinCline yes because the javascript is taking care of it. what i need to fix is when my javascript run it finds the correct file path mail/contact.php

Comment: Tell me exactly where is your js file that calls contact.php and where is contact.php (draw me a hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS, and replace

```
url: "../../mail/contact_me.php",
```

with

```
url: "https://example.com/complete/path/to/mail/contact_me.php",
```

so that your form will be submitted to the correct place. Right now the URL of contact_me.php is relative to either your JS file or your page's URL (depending on whether the JS is inlined or not), and that's asking for trouble.

You could get away with a locally absolute uri aka

```
url: "/complete/path/to/mail/contact_me.php",
```

But that will come back to haunt you if you ever decide to put static files like JS, CSS and images onto another host like a CDN.